# Backbone view Render method default parameter

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a backbone view which is associated with model. View is listening for change method and it calls render if model is changed.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

I'm having a problem that my backbone view's render method is getting called multiple times. I'm trying to debug this problem. For this purpose I added console.log statement in the render method:

```
render: function(data) {
    if(this.model){
        console.log("Render Method:",data," For model:",this.model.cid);
    }
}
```

Now this data value is getting printed as undefined sometimes or something like model. Does anyone know what is the argument passed to a model change listener?

Note that : I'm not passing anything to render method.

and backbone documentation mentions nothing about this: http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#View-render

Comment: The `"change"` event handlers get two arguments: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Comment: You asked: "Does anyone know what is the default parameter passed to render method?" You needed to ask then, what was the arguments passed to a listener of a model change event? Render view does NOT have default parameters.

Comment: I apologize for that Daniel, editing my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change event passes the `model` and a hash of `options`

In backbone [sources](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-48):

```
 this.trigger('change', this, options);
```

And so in the [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Events-catalog) as *mu is too short* has commented:

> "**change**" (model, options) — when a model's attributes have changed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware the render function is not supposed to have any parameters pass to it

```
  Event.Listen=Backbone.View.extend({
          model: 'something'
        initialize:function(){
           this.listenTo(this.model,'change',this.render);

      }
        render:function(){
          //is called when the listen to event is triggered
          //if(this.model) does not make a lot of sense?? Does it need to be 
             //true ornull
           //call another object
           new Event.DoSomething();

        }
   });
```

From the Backbone site "Tell an object to listen to a particular event on an **"other"** object"

Comment: but it does get the parameter somehow, I'm just wondering what that parameter is and if it'd help me debug somehow

Answer (score 0):

Looks like externally to the View there are other calls to render(additional to the event listener).

if you try this(listen to other method instead of render):

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.customMethod);
```

And then declare this in the view below render:

```
customMethod: function() {
    console.log(arguments, '<==== is there arguments?');
    if(this.model){
        console.log("Custom Render Method For model:",this.model.cid);
    }
}
```

So please review in your code, where additional to the model.change listener, you are calling the render method outside the view.

Comment: Sometimes the console won't display the arguments if you leave the function parameter list empty. I'd recommend adding `function(a,b,c,d,e,f){` Adding a long parameter list will ensure that all parameters are displayed. It's overkill, but it works every time.

Comment: @CoryDanielson would you have an example? I've never been in such a case personally so I'm quite interested.

Comment: No, I've just noticed that sometimes the console is weird and won't display arguemnts unless I've given the functions dummy parameters. Could be due to an old version of chrome or something, I'm not sure. It's annoying though.

Answer (score 0):

The event callback gets called multiple times if the binding happens multiple times i.e.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

is being executed multiple times.

It can also happen if the `change` is triggered multiple times. eg. you setting each of the attributes of a model in a for loop rather than at once.

Any call back receives an event as argument.
In your case

```
render: function(data) {
    if(this.model){
        console.log("Render Method:",data," For model:",this.model.cid);
    }
}
```

data will be logged as undefined when `view.render()` is called.
data will be an event object when triggered by a `change` event